# How to access and process Fields of Type Map in a Class using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to access and print all Fields of below mentioned Class (MainClass) using Java Reflection

```
public class MainClass{
  private int aInt;
  private char aChar;
  private boolean aBoolean;
  private Map<Integer, SubClass> subClassMap;

/*** Setters & Getters ***/

}

public class SubClass{
  private long aLong;
  private float aFloat;
  private double aDouble;

/*** Setters & Getters ***/
}
```

It is able to access all Fields and print the details like Type, Name etc using

`(new MainClass()).getClass().getDeclaredFields()`

But how I can access and print the details like *Key* and *Value* part of Field **subClassMap** of Type *Map* (Map<Integer, SubClass>).

I am trying to print all fields & sub-fields of MainClass **recursively** like,

```
** Class MainClass contains following Fields and Objects...
- aInt of Type int
- aChar of Type char
- aBoolean of Type boolean
- subClassMap of Type Map<Integer, SubClass>

   ** SubClass of subClassMap Field contains following Fields and Objects...
   - aLong of Type long
   - aFloat of Type float
   - aDouble of Type double
```

Comment: Your best bet is to make special handling for `Map`s (and probably `List`s too). I don't recommend reflecting into the innards of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much code, so I assume you're looping over the fields something like this:

```
        for (Field field : MainClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            String name = field.getName();
            Class<?> type = field.getType();
            Object value = field.get(mainClassInstance);
        }
```

What you should do is have special handling for when you hit "known" types, such as `Map`:

```
        for (Field field : MainClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                Map<?,?> map = (Map<?, ?>) field.get(mainClass);
                System.out.println("Found a map " + map);
                for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s %s: %s%n", field.getType(), field.getName(), field.get(mainClass));
            }
        }
```

You can extend this for `List`s, and even for your own types like `SubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
subClassMap=[{1=SubClass [aLong=1234567, aFloat=2.0, aDouble=2.234], 2=SubClass [aLong=31234567, aFloat=32.0, aDouble=32.234]}]
```

Use `toString()` method in both classes.

MainClass:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "subClassMap=[" + subClassMap + "]";
}
```

SubClass:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SubClass [aLong=" + aLong + ", aFloat=" + aFloat + ", aDouble=" + aDouble + "]";
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). I don't see how the code in your answer uses reflection.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... But how I can access and print the details like *Key* and *Value* part of Field **subClassMap** of Type *Map* (Map<Integer, SubClass>). ...*

You're looking to use the *[Field#getGenericType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType())* method, instead of the *[getType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType())* method.

And, resourcefully the *getGenericType* method will fall back to the *getType* method, if the class does not have any *type variables*.

Here is the source; *[GitHub – OpenJDK – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Field.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Field.java#L292),*

```java
public Type getGenericType() {
    if (getGenericSignature() != null)
        return getGenericInfo().getGenericType();
    else
        return getType();
}
```

Here is an example, with the classes you provided.

```java
System.out.println(MainClass.class.getSimpleName());
for (Field field : MainClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
    System.out.printf("- %s of Type %s%n", field.getName(), field.getGenericType());
        
System.out.println(SubClass.class.getSimpleName());
for (Field field : SubClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
    System.out.printf("- %s of Type %s%n", field.getName(), field.getGenericType());
```

Output

```
MainClass
- aInt of Type int
- aChar of Type char
- aBoolean of Type boolean
- subClassMap of Type java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, SubClass>
SubClass
- aLong of Type long
- aFloat of Type float
- aDouble of Type double
```

Comment: Thanks Reilas, getGenericType() helped to print Key and Value part of MainClass.subClassMap. But I am trying to print all fields and sub-fields **recursively** (sorry I didn't mention it specifically, will update my question accordingly)